# React - when to call react as a variable vs import react

Tags: reactjs

I work at a company with a large react code base... not all of it is to react standards, and not all of it adheres to it's own standards (im thinking this is pretty standard haha).

I see react being brought into components differently throughout. Here's two examples - marked with (1) and (2):

```
(1) let React = require('react');
(2) import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
```

What is the difference and why use one versus the other? It's not only the `react` being brought in. I also see `import {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';` and `let {Component} = React;`.

I did a brief search on them internets and couldnt find what i was looking for. maybe my search terms are off a bit. Id be happy with brief explanation and hopefully documentation to go with it. Thank you.

Comment: The first one is commonjs/requirejs syntax. It's added using a library. The second is official ES6 standard syntax. In many situations they are interchangeable. The biggest difference is that `import` has to be always constant while `require` is entirely dynamic, you can pass any generated string there.

Comment: I was able to find quite a lot of info on this on the internet. Did you really search? :D

Comment: @Chris, not as well as I could have, I'm sure. When my search took me way off course I decided to go here. When I didnt see it here, I asked here. btw, searching on SO I've run into your responses in the past. Thanks for writing all the responses, they've really helped me out.

Comment: @Lefty, *"my"* responses?

Answer (score 5):

The difference between the two is that

```
1) let React = require('react');
```

is ES5 syntax, whereas

```
2)  import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
```

is ES6 syntax

However no Javascript engine as yet supporst ES6 and hence some utility tools like babel behind the scenes convert the ES6 definition to the ES5 syntax of require which @azium says is the Node commonJS syntax for importing modules only.

Comment: rather than es5 vs es6, is more like Node's commonJS import syntax vs ES6 import syntax. es5 did not have any standards for modules

Answer (score 0):

- 1) is syntax of ECMAScript 5 (ES5) published in 2009
- 2) is syntax of    ECMAScript 6 (ES6) also known as ECMAScript 2015
  (ES2015) published    in 2015

> ```
> (1) let React = require('react');
> (2) import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
> ```